# What are the "irreducible factors" in an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

What are the irreducible factors in an algebra? In the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelsohn, page 35, line 1, there occurs "take irreducible factors of...", but I don't know what irreducible factor is. Can any one explain what is it, or give some reference about this?

Comment: I think Lawson/Michelsohn mean "take an irreducible subrepresentation of the representation of $\mathcal{Cl}_n$ on $\mathcal{Cl}_n^+$ and an irreducible subrepresentation of the representation of $\mathcal{Cl}_n$ on $\mathcal{Cl}_n^-$".

Comment: Thank you very much! This does make sense, I will make it precise.

Comment: @Lao-tzu I think darij is probably spot-on, but I'll ask anyway. You quit too early in your question: "take the irreducible factors of..." a representation? module? algebra? The key context seems to be missing.

Comment: @rschwieb The context is: "To see that both possibilities exist take irreducible factors of $Cl_n$ acting on $Cl_n^+$ and on $Cl_n^-$ by multiplication from the left." But now I think this paragraph is no need for proving the proposition, and even now I cannot understand why the authors wrote this. For the full context, you'd better check for that book.

Comment: @Lao-tzu OK: that clarifies things. Thanks!